# Trouble getting image to display in TKinter

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter

I have the following simplified code from my project. My error lies in the line

```
self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = lambda: show)
```

The error message spyder gives me is that the name 'show' is not defined, even though it is a function I clearly define in the class.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = 100
y = 100
xtmi = 200
xtma = 205 
xs = 1024
ytmi = 500
ytma = 505
ys = 768
xarr = np.zeros(x)
yarr = np.zeros(y)
output = np.meshgrid(xarr,yarr)
output=output[0]
def mkPIL(array):
    im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(array))
    return im
im = mkPIL(output)
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')


import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas, Label


root = tk.Tk()

root.mainloop()


class Manipulation:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.kill = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Kill', width = 25, command = self.close)
        self.kill.pack()
        self.displayimg = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Display', width = 25, command = lambda: show)
        self.displayimg.pack()
    def close(self): 
        self.master.destroy()
    def show(): 
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        panel = Label(root, image=im)
        panel.image = img
        panel.place(x=0,y=0)
```

Comment: A reference to the image is never saved. You create it in a function and not as a class attribute. This image is garbage collect after the function completes. To fix this turn that function into a method and the saved image to a class attribute.

Comment: ***"the name 'show' is not defined"***: This should read `command=self.show` and `def show(self):` Read up on [Python Classes and Objects, Section "The self"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-classes-and-objects/)

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: `panel = Label(root, image=im)` should be `panel = Label(root, image=img)` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, my code works now. I just have to properly position the image.